# Performance: Using try (statement) and catch (output error) instead of checking if email already exist

Tags: php, performance, pdo, database-performance, query-performance

Very often i need to prevent querys to get executed when a value like a email already exist.

Until now i searched for the value like that:

```
$checkemailexist = $X['db']->prepare("SELECT uid FROM userdata WHERE uid = :uid LIMIT 1");
$checkemailexist->execute(array(
':uid'=>$uid
));

if(empty($checkemailexist)){
   INSERT QUERY ..
}
```

...

The problem on a big database with many rows, a string search even on a varchar can take a lot of performance and time.

So i made the uid column unique and tried something like that:

```
try{    
    $insertuser = $X['dbh']->prepare("
    INSERT INTO user (uid) VALUES (:uid) 
    ");

    $insertuser->execute(array(
    ':uid'=> $mail
    ));

} catch (PDOException $e) {
        header("Location: ...");
        exit(); 
}
```

**Its working fine, but could the performance even be worse ?**

Comment: there is no difference. It's neither better or worse.

Comment: The `INSERT` is very likely worse in terms of performance because it will trigger all sorts of DB-level exceptions which you do not see and it probably runs a select anyways to see if that UID exists. The only 100% fool-proof answer is to loop your queries and see the performance difference for yourself.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus     atm i cant test on a big database to see any different.

Comment: Okay, so what do you want me to do about it?

Comment: Waiting for someone who has already tried or know about ;D.

Comment: Looking back at your first example. Are you implying that you perform the `SELECT` first followed by an `INSERT`? If yes, then option 2 is definitely faster because it requires only one SQL execution.

Comment: Everyone's environment and database is different so other people's observations  do not guarantee the same outcome for you.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus     yep first of all im searching if the email exist, if not then i will insert in a second query, if not error output.

Comment: Yeah, that's totally inefficient. The single `INSERT` on a unique ID constrained column will always win. You should consider adding that kind of info right away next time.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus     im sorry, from my perspective it was clear. I edit the question.

Comment: Oh well. Apparently @YourCommonSense is far more psychic than me so it's a good thing they gave a proper answer.

Comment: `UNIQUE` is your best friend. If I'm not wrong, the search on an `UNIQUE` field is done using *binary search*, that means that in the worst case, your DB will perform `log2(NumberOfRows)` checks before figuring out that the value is missing. On a 1 billions rows table, this is about 30 checks. If someone can confirm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After making uid column an [unique] index, you made *all* your queries faster. Both queries, either SELECT or INSERT will have to check the index, and it will **take them both the same time** to perform.

**Adding an index to the column used for search for is the real answer to your question**. As to whether to use a select query or to catch an exception during insert is a matter of taste.

However, your second example is rather wrong. You shouldn't handle every PDOException the same way but only a specific exception related to this very case, as it's shown in my [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch).

The best way would be to keep the unique index but add a keyword IGNORE to the query and then check the number of affected rows

```
$insertuser = $X['dbh']->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO user (uid) VALUES (:uid)");
$insertuser->execute(['uid'=> $mail]));
if (!$insertuser->numRows()) {
    header("Location: ...");
    exit(); 
}
```

adding IGNORE would suppress the unique index error, and you will be able to check whether such a value already exists by simply checking the number of affected rows

Comment: Yep this is very genius to use IGNORE, works perfect thanks a lot.